# getting {myTopic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED} in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, oauth-2.0

I am following https://medium.com/egen/how-to-configure-oauth2-authentication-for-apache-kafka-cluster-using-okta-8c60d4a85b43 for setting up OAuth2.0

But when I try to produce data I get  Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 43 : {myTopic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}.

Can anyone please help me out

I tried adding invalid details in my sasl-oauth2-consumerapp-config.properties file to check if it is picking the right file , it seems like right file is picked.